# Memory leak when read file in C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

here is my code:

```
// the read func
vector<string> read(string file_name){
    ifstream ifs(file_name, ifstream::in);
    string line;
    vector<string> company_names;
    while(getline(ifs, line)){
        company_names.push_back(line);
    }
    return company_names;
}


void test(){
    vector<string> company = read("/home/yanwii/SocialCredits/CompanyName/company_names.txt");
    vector<string>().swap(company);
}

int main(){
    test();
}
```

After loading from file, in htop the program occupied 2G, then After swapping, the program still occupied 1G, what's going wrong?

Comment: Nothing - C++ does not always return memory to the OS. This is to improve performance

Comment: Is there any way to release it or i have to rebuild a vector like class? @EdHeal ?

Comment: Did you mean that the program *still occupies 2G* after the swap operation?

Comment: The OS will reclaim RAM (but not address space) when other programs need it. So there's only limited benefit in C++ returning address space to the OS.

Comment: It only reduced by half.@Clearer

Comment: Post the exact output of `htop` so people are sure which RAM figure you are talking about. Anyway, you won't get anything by "rebuild[ing] a vector like class" because this is a function of how your OS manages memory, not C++; nothing is leaked by the code, and all dynamic memory owned by stdlib classes will already be freed properly*, and you won't be able to do any better than they do. (* Unless you have a bug in your stdlib, which is vanishingly unlikely this late in the game.)

Comment: @underscore_d it's not because of the OS, it's first of all because of `malloc` implementation, which may never return memory allocation back to the OS. In particular, glibc is known to behave this way, while jemalloc does return memory.

Comment: @yanwii - After you have allocated and released large amounts of memory, the runtime expects you to likely do that again soon. So it keeps some heap memory available for reuse.